# localStorage is null on options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the options page of a chrome extension, localStorage is null and thus can not be used.
Here are the files of the unpacked extension producing error.

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "someTest",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Not important",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

#### options.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Just a test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### options.js

```
console.log(localStorage);
```

Accessing the options page, the console outputs `null`. When trying to change or access a property using `localStorage['property']`, it throws an error since localStorage is null.

I tried something like `localStorage = {property: 'value'};` but it did not change anything, after that localStorage was still null.

I'm using chrome 28.0.1500.95 on Windows 8.

**Edit:** The issue is still there. However, I -for the moment- use an alternative, if it can help someone. I now use chrome storage.

Here is how it works.

#### manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

#### options.js

```
//You can also use an array of strings instead of 'property' to get multiple values.
chrome.storage.local.get('property', function(data)
{
    if(!data.propery) return; //Not set
    console.log(data.property);
});
chrome.storage.local.set({property: 'value'}, function()
{
    console.log('saved');
});
//It can be used the same way directly in content scripts.
```

Comment: Either way, use `localStorage.setItem("key", "value")` and `localStorage.getItem("key")` (and `localStorage.removeItem("key")`)

Comment: Yeah I just tried do to it like the [official google exemple](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html). But `setItem` and all don't work neither since localStorage is `null`.

Comment: When you open the console on the options page (Ctrl+Shift+J), and type in `localStorage`, you also see `null` that way as well?

Comment: Hum, that's odd. I just tried with exactly what you put (I just removed the icon part from the manifest), and it works fine for me. I have a hard time thinking of where it could come from (other extensions or Chrome version seem unlikely). For the record, I use Chrome version 30.0.1599.0 dev.

Comment: Worked for me with your exact code, I'm on Chrome 28.0 Windows 7.  Are you sure you're in Options.html's console window?

Comment: Yes. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/mZJVgg5.png) of what I get. Note that when I run `options.html` from the explorer (not in the extension context), everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to access it via the [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage):

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(win) {
   console.log(win.localStorage.property);
});
```

Note: I’m not seeing the problem you’re seeing. I’m just suggesting a possible workaround.

Comment: I just noticed I didn't try your answer. Sadly I do not have the same problem anymore (localStorage is working fine) so I can't know if your solution would have fixed it. I am going to suppose it would have worked and accept your answer.